# Can be this lisp function be implemented recursively?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The goal of this function is to generate the cartesian product of 2 list.
For example

- (combo (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5))  => (1 4) (1 5) (2 4) (2 5) (3 4) (3 5)

  ```
  (defun combo (l1 l2)
  (let    (
              (res (list))
          )
      (dolist (elem1 l1 res)
          (dolist (elem2 l2 res)
              (setq res (append res (list(list elem1 elem2))))
          )
      )
  )
  ```

  )

How could be implemented recursively?

Comment: Yes, it can be implemented recursively.

Comment: Note that your function is very inefficient. Check the use of APPEND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple recursive implementation would be to use two helper functions; one to traverse through `L1` (`%COMBO` in the code below), calling another function to pair an element with each element from `L2` (`%PRODUCT`):

```
(defun combo (l1 l2)
  (labels ((%product (el list &optional (acc (list)))
             (if (endp list)
                 acc
                 (%product el (rest list) (cons (list el (first list)) acc))))
           (%combo (l1 l2 &optional (acc (list)))
             (if (endp l1)
                 (nreverse acc)
                 (%combo (rest l1) l2 (nconc (%product (first l1) l2) acc)))))
    (%combo l1 l2)))
```

The iterative approach is both simpler and more efficient though. Instead of using `APPEND` in a loop, you should just reverse the list at the end.

```
(defun combo (l1 l2)
  (let ((res (list)))
    (dolist (e1 l1 (nreverse res))
      (dolist (e2 l2)
        (push (list e1 e2) res)))))
```

You could also just use the `MAP-PRODUCT` function from [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/):

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :alexandria)
;=> (:ALEXANDRIA)
CL-USER> (use-package :alexandria)
;=> T
CL-USER> (map-product #'list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5))
;=> ((1 4) (1 5) (2 4) (2 5) (3 4) (3 5))
```

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks. :)

Comment: What is the role of (nreverse res)  in your second solution?

Comment: @rnso `PUSH` adds an object to the front of the list, so the list has to be reversed at the end to get the results in order. Using `APPEND` in a loop is bad because every time you call it, you're creating a new copy of the list. Lists in lisp are singly linked, so you can make a new list with elements added to the front without having to copy or modify the tail, but adding anything to the back requires either creating a new copy, or destructively modifying the list. Using `PUSH` and `NREVERSE` is the usual Common Lisp idiom for building a list of results.

Answer (score -1):

It seems ideal for Prolog, though data has to be put differently:

```
items1(1).
items1(2).
items1(3).

items2(4).
items2(5).

?- findall((A,B), (items1(A), items2(B)), L).
L = [ (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5)].
```