# Permutations including all members in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Extending on this question [Can be this lisp function be implemented recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976330/can-be-this-lisp-function-be-implemented-recursively/37977256#comment63896601_37977256) , is it possible to have all combinations in Prolog if the lists are represented like following:

```
items1(1, 2, 3).
items2(4, 5).
```

I can get the answer with following format of data:

```
items1(1).
items1(2).
items1(3).

items2(4).
items2(5).

?- findall((A,B), (items1(A), items2(B)), L).
L = [ (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5)].
```

I checked the permutation predicate from http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=permutation/2 but that is for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have already solved your problem quite nicely, by normalizing your database. It is inconvenient to represent a list `[I_1, I_2, ..., I_n]` as a fact `items(I_1, I_2, ..., I_n).`. Lists are meant for (possibly ordered) collections that have 0 or more elements; facts are usually meant for tables with a preset number of columns, with one fact per row. And these two representations:

1. `[a, b, c]` (a list), and
2. `item(a). item(b). item(c).` (a table of facts)

are in fact very similar. Choosing one or another is a matter of how you want to use it, and it is quite easy (and common) to convert from the one to another in your program. For example, `?- member(X, [a, b, c]).` is about the same as `?- item(X).` when you have (2) defined. The Prolog list version of [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976330/can-be-this-lisp-function-be-implemented-recursively) would be:

```
combo(L1, L2, X-Y) :-
    member(X, L1),
    member(Y, L2).
```

And then:

```
?- combo([1,2,3], [4,5], R).
R = 1-4 ;
R = 1-5 ;
R = 2-4 ;
R = 2-5 ;
R = 3-4 ;
R = 3-5.
```

A bit less inconvenient (but still unnecessary) would be to write `items([a, b, c]).`, so you have one argument, a list of all items. Then, you can do:

```
?- items(Is),
   member(X, Is).
```

If you really have something like `items(a, b, c).`, *and* you know that you have exactly three items, you could still do:

```
?- items(A, B, C),
   member(X, [A, B, C]).
```

If you don't know at compile time the arity of `items`, you need to examine the program at run time. If your program looks as in your question:

```
items1(1, 2, 3).
items2(4, 5).
```

Then you could for example do:

```
?- current_predicate(items1/N), % figure out the arity of items1
   length(Is, N),               % make a list of that length
   Fact =.. [items1|Is],        % create a callable term
   Fact,                        % call the term to instantiate Is
   member(X, Is).               % enumerate the list
```

As you see, quite round-about.

One more comment: It is unusual to use `(A,B)` as a "tuple" in Prolog. For a pair, you would usually write `A-B`, and if you don't know how many elements you have, it's usually just a list, for example `[A,B|Rest]`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932359/1812457) and the comments below it for more detail.

Comment: Great answers. Thanks.

Comment: @rnso I am still a bit surprised that the Lisp version of this is so roundabout. There must be an easier way to do it....

Comment: More experienced persons like you can comment on Prolog vs Lisp. Have you already posted on this earlier?